# How to get values from database for editing a multiselect field

Tags: php, mysql, multi-select

I am currently trying to get the values from my database to put it in a multiselect field.

This is the code I have been trying to develop, but which is currently not working

```
<select id="cycledevie" name="cycledevie[]" multiple>
<?php

//Etablissement de la connection à la base de donnée en localhost, utilisateur root, sans mot de passe
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");

//Selection de la base de donnée
$db = mysqli_select_db($conn, "bddprojet");

$resultTable = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM cycledevie");
$resultData = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM cycledevie where IdRisque='1'");

if (!$resultTable) {
    echo "Impossible d'exécuter la requête : " . mysqli_error();
    exit;
}
if (!$resultData) {
    echo "Impossible d'exécuter la requête : " . mysqli_error();
    exit;
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($resultData) > 0 && mysqli_num_rows($resultTable) > 0) {
    while ($rowData = mysqli_fetch_array($resultData) && $rowTable = mysqli_fetch_array($resultTable)) {
        if ($rowTable[0] == 'IdRisque') {
            echo 'bonjour';
        }else{
            echo '<option value=' . $rowTable[0] . '>' . $rowTable[0] . '</option>';
        }
    }
}
?>
</select>
```

My table "cycledevie" is going to be updated in the future with some new columns, so I would like to print the name of the columns as an option to be selected. Then, in the database, if the column is equal to 1, I would like that the option appears as "selected", and if it is a 0, it appears as an unselected option.
Here is a screen of my table "cycledevie"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJYxq.png)
If you have any question, or if I haven't been clear enought, let me know.
Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: **Not Working** is a very poor description of your problem. What does it do? what does it not do? Are there any error messages? Did you look at the PHP Error logs? If so were there any errors??

Comment: Well actually it doesn't do anything, except printing me an empty multiselect... I don't have any Php error logs, or any erros messages, so I think that the problem come from the way I am calling my functions... Don't hesitate if I am not clear enought

Comment: You dont have any PHP Error log? Or do you mean there are no errors in the logs

Comment: So you see the dropdown, but there is no data inside it? Is that right??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to have a maintainable database, you should apply some changes to it. Each time you add a table to a database or a column to a table, you change the database's structure and then you need to migrate to apply those changes in production. As you said you need to add cycles eventually, you must look for a table like this :

[image]

You will be able to add as many cycles as you wish (or to remove them) without the needs of a migration.

Then, you can select and fetch datas this way for your multiselect field :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

include('database.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lifecycle";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);  

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    
      echo "<select name='cycles' id='cycles' style='height:200px;' multiple>";

      // output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      
        if($row['isRisky']) {
        
            echo "<option value='" . $row['cycle'] . "' selected>" . $row['cycle'] . "</option>";
        
        } else {
        
            echo "<option value='" . $row['cycle'] . "'>" . $row['cycle'] . "</option>";
        
        }
    
      }
    
      echo "</select>";
    
    } 

    $conn->close();
    
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the final result :

[image]

Further on, you must use a submit button into a form if you wish to apply a treatment to those datas...